# Kendo's Angular Scheduler is still in Beta. What are limitations?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, scheduler

Kendo's Angular Scheduler component is still in Beta.
What are the limitations which i need to take care 
go forward to use it for outlook style calendar scheduler?

https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-angular-ui/scheduler

https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-angular-ui/scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Mostly bugs. 
You can check the list with issues here:
[kendo-angular scheduler](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3Apkg%3Ascheduler)

From my experience a few months ago there were few bugs with reccurence rule (like interval, custom rule, end rule) and another one with TimeZones which I think is fixed now.

Most of the bugs I have found was fixed in the next version, just after I registered them as an issue on github.

So in my opinion you can go for it if you not going to put it in produciton right away. There is not something THAT critical as a problem.